# TableView methods get called before JSON data is parsed?

Tags: json, swift, api, uitableview, indexoutofrangeexception

I have called the function to parse json from the viewDidLoad method itself, but it goes directly to resume() after "let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) {(data, response, error) in" line.
And then table view methods get called which return 0 for numberOfRowsInSection and also an "index out of range" error for "cellForRowAt indexPath"!

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        downloadJSON()
    }
    
    func downloadJSON() {
        
        let url = URL(string: "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&apiKey=4cf7331ecee44bef80b632fd4c1ba6b3")
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) {(data, response, error) in
            
            if error == nil {
                do {
                    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(APIResponse.self, from: data!)
                    self.news = result.articles
                    self.numberOfRows = result.articles.count
                    print("Articles: \(result.articles.count)")
                }
                catch {
                    print("JSON Error")
                }
            }
            
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.newsTableView.reloadData()
        }
            
        }.resume()
        
        
    }

//MARK:- Table View Methods
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       // return news.count! // returns 0
        return 20
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! NewsTableViewCell
        print(indexPath.row, news.count)
        //cell.authorName.text = self.news[indexPath.row].author  // (index out of range error)
        return cell
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The call to api is asynchronous so your array is initially empty and putting 20 will make a crash as the table reloads when the vc appears so you should supply your data source array size

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   return news.count 
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { 
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! NewsTableViewCell 
    cell.authorName.text = self.news[indexPath.row].author  
    return cell 
}
```

Declare it like this

```
var news = [News]() // Don't declare it optional
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I have declared the news like this only. "var news = [Article]()" But why does it not execute these lines " if error == nil {
                do {
                    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(APIResponse.self, from: data!)
                    self.news = result.articles
                    self.numberOfRows = result.articles.count
                    print("Articles: \(result.articles.count)")
                }"

Comment: may be you have a decoding error do `print(error)`

Comment: the (data, response, error ) it is itself not being executed.  I just debugged it. task is getting 0 elements